# get variable from umbraco form using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, umbraco

I have a jquery that I need to get a variable decleared inside the form

currently jquery line is

```
$.ajax {
    var GId = $('#globalSettingsId').val();
..... Rest of script 
}
```

the globalSettingsId is deleared in the umbraco form first couple of lines

```
@{
    int globalSettingsId = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["globalSettingsID"]);

...... Form layout Code .....
}
```

the script fails to run as is

Comment: Your syntax for initializing `$.ajax` is completely invalid javascript. Use your browser developer tools console to check for errors and read documentation for proper implemntation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

Need to have an Html representation of the variable.

```
@Html.Hidden("globalSettingsId", globalSettingsId)
```

Comment: Ok. so that was solved but what if my variable I need to access is the model from a partial view loaded on the form.

Comment: Ok. so that was solved but what if my variable I need to access is the model from a partial view loaded on the form.

Answer (score 0):

sorry ajax was removed script is exactly as is here

```
<script scr="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#MemberSelect').change(function () {
            var PreviousId = $('#MemberSelect').val();
            var MemberId = $('#MemberSelect').val();
            var MId = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Id));
            //var GId = $('#globalSettingsId').val();
            $('#MemberDetails').load('@Url.Action("MemberMaintenance", "IBDMembershipFormSurface")' + '?MemId=' + MemberId + '&NodeID=' + MId); // + '&GlobalSettingsID=' + GId);
        });
    });
</script>
```

the line commented out is the one I need to solve